# Is there a built-in graphical way to set the DNS on elementaryOS Loki?

Tags: networking, user-interface

Is there a way to set the used DNS in elementaryOS Loki in a graphical manner?

The following is the only working way that I have found to change the DNS when using DNSCrypt...

1. Editing **/etc/resolv.conf** which is a symlink for **/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf** and adding to it:

> nameserver 127.0.0.1

One can use Scratch for editing the file, but I wondered if there was a way to change the used DNS in GUI software like in the Network Settings of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**:  (Follow only for loopback DNS addresses)

Disable **dnsmasq** in **/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf** by comenting the line that contains **dns=dnsmasq** with a hash symbol (#). Like this:

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

**Step 2**:

- Open the **Network Settings** and in the connection of interest,
  select **Settings**...
- Navigate to the **IPv4 Settings** tab and
  there, select the option **Automatic (DHCP) addresses only** from the
  **Method** field.
- Then, on the **DNS servers** field, write the address of
  the DNS to use. In this case **127.0.0.1**.
- Hit **Save**.

[image: Network Settings]

**Step 3**:

Restart the network manager service with the following command

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Notes: If you use remote DNS server addresses, like 8.8.8.8, you don't need to disable dnsmasq. You can skip to Step 2. Step 1 is only for when using loopback addresses, like with DNSCrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a network connection in Network Settings, then you are able to add `additional DNS servers` which will work alongside the automatic ones from DHCP (which are generally provided by networking hardware / ISP), or else you can specify to use only the DNS servers you want by selecting `Manual` or `Automatic DHCP (Addresses Only)`

This is in the IPv4 and IPv6 tabs of the settings.

Editing `/etc/resolv.conf` manually doesn't persist, it will be automatically overwritten (which is normal as different connections require different DNS like office intranet etc.), so I'd move away from that approach if possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. It did help a little bit. Thanks! Though a few more steps had to be taken for the written directions to work. I solved it by disabling dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf as described in the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away. And then following your directions. For some reason I still don't understand, when dnsmasq is enabled, it didn't work for me. Thanks again.